# Android NDK release flag

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I'm using the Android NDK (integrated with CMake and gradle). 
Currently the C++ Release-Flag is automatically set dependent on the Android Build-Type (Release/Debug). 
I'd like to compile/link the native code **always** with the release flag. How can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: I understand what "Android Build Type" is, but what is "C++ Release-Flag"? Do you mean **compiler** flags like `-DNDEBUG` or `-O3`?

Comment: Since the NDK part is built with CMake, you can pass "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" (or Debug) to the CMake build. It automatically sets some "Release Build Flags"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the module build.gradle (for example, app/build.gradle), inside android {} block, add:

```
android {
   ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
        }
    }
}
```

This would overwrite the default debug settings as arguments are appended to default settings. Check the generated build files at .externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/$arch :

- cmake_build_command.txt
- android_gradle_build.json

Answer (score 0):

Gerry's answer does not work for me.

If anyone has the same problem, you can try use the config shown in [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#variables)

For example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('../app/src/main/cpp/your-proj/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}
```